# Can't make AES encryption to be working between PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, unity-game-engine

I had spent 3 days, trying to implement a simple encrypted communication in my Unity 3D application. The thing is, that response from the php script is giving me weird characters.

That's my C# code:

```
private const string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

public static string Decrypt(string data)
{
    byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    byte[] toDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();

    aes.Key = keyArray;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] resultBytes = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecrypt, 0, toDecrypt.Length);

    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
}

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(test());
}

private IEnumerator test()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("http://x.com/game/getInfo.php?text=" + Security.Encrypt("test"));
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(Security.Decrypt(www.text));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
    }
}
```

And my php code:

```
<?php
$key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 

function Encrypt($string){
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}

function Decrypt($string){
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}

$toEncrypt = Decrypt($_GET['text']);
echo Encrypt(toEncrypt);
?>
```

Everytime Debug.Log prints another string like "a'�@н���:�j" or "��e?e���\ �V��", instead of "test". I have no idea why. I tried encoding it in UTF8, using openssl methods, changing key length, and I'm still getting these weird characters.

Is there anything I omitted here?

Comment: How long is your key really? This doesn't look like a 128 bit "key". C# takes the provided key and sets the key size according to the provided key by itself.

Comment: Right. I missed the length :/
My key is now 16 characters long. I've modified C# code to:
`for (;;)
        {
            WWW www = new WWW("http://x.com/game/getInfo.php?text=" + Security.Encrypt("test"));
            yield return www;
            Debug.Log("Original: " + www.text + ". Decrypted: " + Security.Decrypt(www.text));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
        }`

It still isn't able to decrypt the message:
"Original: TF7prqjJdx/F6OLIrjCpFQ==. Decrypted: ��@xI�*��+B@("

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: You need to take a break and learn about binary and encoding such as ASCII, unicode, Hexadecimal and Base64. They you will understand why you are getting gibberish and how to properly view encrypted data (and data in general).

Comment: @zaph Okay, thank you very much :) 
I'll dive into these encodings once more and use RNCryptor, I think.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the same key. Your "key" is a sequence of 32 characters. When encoding that key, you get a byte array of 32 bytes. This is a "key" of 256 bits. When you set `aes.KeySize = 128;`, this changes the key size that you want, which also generates a completely different key ([example](http://ideone.com/edggd9)).

If you want to use AES-256, then you have to remove `aes.KeySize = 128;`. Just changing 128 to 256 wouldn't change anything ([exmaple](http://ideone.com/3YBO7A)).

---

#### Security considerations:

- The key needs to be similar to random noise. You can generate a random key and store it in encoded form (Hex/Base64) in the source code, but only if the source code or the resulting executable are never given to other parties.
- **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.